# Парсинг HTML c библиотекой HtmlСleaner

Tags: html, java

В примере [парсинг HTML c библиотекой HtmlСleaner](http://www.javatalks.ru/ftopic24660/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-HTML-c-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-Html%D0%A1leaner) рассказывается, как превратить кусок html в валидный xml. Нужно выполнить строку

```
java -jar htmlcleaner-2.2.jar src=source.html dest=source.xml
```

А как такое сделать не в командной строке, а в сервлете? Когда в сервлет приходит ссылка на страницу, которую нужно парсить. Вместо source.xml писать ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

На сайте библиотеки есть же все с кучей примеров: http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php

ЗЫ. На всякий случай поясню: запускать из сервлета нужно не через командную строку, а непосредственно через саму библиотеку HTMLCleaner.